# Unable to copy default register user action in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to copy the default register user action from the MVC template, when I copy the method to another class I get the following errors.

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong? I'm stumped.

> incorrect number of type parameters
>
> cannot resolve symbol Succeeded
>
> Cannot resolve symbol add errors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 2 other methods from the template. First one to get the `UserManager` object:

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

Secondly, `AddErrors`:

```
private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
{
    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
    }
}
```